# How to call mongoose in blocking mode inside expressjs callback?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to call mongoose in blocking mode inside an express callback. The problem is tha I can't use await iside the callback. How should I do it?

```
app.post('/order', (req, res) => {
    if (reqLogin(req)) {
        console.log(req.body);
        var order = new Order({
            client: {
                name: "test",
                phone: "123456789"
            },
            products: [{
                name: "product1",
                quantity: 3,
                price: 100
            }]
        });
        try {
            await order.save();
            res.send(jsonOk);
        } catch (err) {
            LOG(err);
        }
    } else {
        res.send(jsonWrongPassword);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try marking your callback as `async`? i.e. `async (req, res) => ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by JohnnyHK, You need to make your callback function into an `async` function. At the given stage of your code when executed it should throw an error :: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`, it's because `await` operator  has to be used inside an `async` function, Otherwise your code will throw an error, `await` will make code work in blocking way making process to wait at that point - it will either be resolved or rejected & will then move forward, Check this :

```
app.post('/order', async (req, res) => {
    if (reqLogin(req)) {
        console.log(req.body);
        var order = new Order({
            client: {
                name: "test",
                phone: "123456789"
            },
            products: [{
                name: "product1",
                quantity: 3,
                price: 100
            }]
        });
        try { // Yes this correct code using async-await is better to be wrapped in try/catch for error handling
            await order.save();
            res.send(jsonOk);
        } catch (err) {
            LOG(err);
        }
    } else {
        res.send(jsonWrongPassword);
    }
});
```

**Ref :** [JavaScript-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)